# Why are useState variables `const` in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

My understanding is, when using `useState()`, we should declare the array as such:

```
const [someBooleanValue, setSomeBooleanValue] = useState(false)
```

Instead of

```
let [someBooleanValue, setSomeBooleanValue] = useState(false)
```

Normally, `const` is used on variables that won't be changing. Here, `someBooleanValue` will be changing. What is going on that allows us to use the `const` keyword in this case?

Comment: Because useState are immutable. On this case they using const because this is array destruction instead of defining variables.

Comment: `const` is for a variable that is not reassigned. This prohibits you from manually assigning a value to `someBooleanValue`.

Comment: @Satif even though it is array destructuring, it is still defining variables.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13982#issuecomment-433349510

Comment: The variable isn't changing. Every time state changes react re-renders the component, which is a new function call, and your `consts` are being redeclared. React is keeping track of what the values should be the next time they are declared which is what leads to the confusion about the consts changing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why React Hook useState uses const and not let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58860021/why-react-hook-usestate-uses-const-and-not-let)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) with a Functional Component, your code gets a single value of state for each call into your functional component. React handles the storage separately and returns that current value via `useState` on each execution of your code, providing the latest state value.

From the docs:

> We declare a state variable called count, and set it to 0. **React will remember its current value between re-renders, and provide the most recent one to our function.** If we want to update the current count, we can call setCount.

So in this case, we use `const` because the value should never be reassigned in our code.

Answer (score 0):

In the functional component, we declare the state using const.
To update the state we have to go through a specific method that uses the Set function. It is completely fine to change the state by using the Set process.

We use const to avoid reassignment of state. That's shit!!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using 'const' keyword we can't re-initialize an already declared variable. More specifically that means you can't give a new memory location to a variable declared with 'const'.

```
const name = 'john'

name = 'doe' // error
```

But strings and numbers are primitives value. So assigning a new string and number will point the 'name' variable to a new memory location. Thats why node will throw error.

But what about array and objects =>

```
const names = []

['mike', 'tyson', 'john'].forEach(item => {
     names.push(item)
})
```

Arrays and objects are mutable. That means it doesn't give a new memory location to the 'names' variable when pushing items to it. Its mutating in place memory.

But in "React" every 'state' variables needs a new memory location to re-render and display the new values in the page. Thats why if you try to mutate the state variable, it will throw error which refers you, reset the states memory location using set Methods.

In short: 'const' keyword are used more likely to idealize the react state declaration to warn developers to reset the memory location of the state to re-render and reflect the changes in the page.